# Dealing with editable items in a filtered UITable with an NSMutableArray copy

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITable with a datasource that is set to a 'copy' of the original data. I use this copy to displayed filtered results (either 'All' or only those that are 'checked' with a UISwitch in each row). My logic for doing the filtering is here:

```
-(void)filterItems {
[tableData removeAllObjects];
if (checkedOrNotSwitch.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
    [tableData addObjectsFromArray:self.defaultChecklistItemsArray];
} else {
    for (NSMutableDictionary *sectionDict in self.defaultChecklistItemsArray) {
        NSMutableArray *newItemsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [newItemsArray removeAllObjects];
        for (NSMutableDictionary *itemDict in [sectionDict objectForKey:@"categoryItems"]) {
            if ([[itemDict objectForKey:@"isComplete"] boolValue]) {
                [newItemsArray addObject:itemDict];
            }
        }
        if ([newItemsArray count] > 0) {
            NSMutableDictionary *newSectionDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:sectionDict];
            [newSectionDict setObject:newItemsArray forKey:@"categoryItems"];
            [tableData addObject:newSectionDict];
            [newSectionDict release];
        }
    }
}
[checklistTable reloadData];
```

}

The filtering itself now works correctly. In my custom cell, each row has a UISwitch. The switch runs this function when its changed:

```
-(IBAction) switchValueChanged{
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [(UITableView *)self.superview indexPathForCell: self];
[self.parentController updateCompletedStatusAtIndexPath:indexPath toStatus:isCompleted.on];
```

}

The function above is in the class for the tableviewcell itself. The function I call in the superview is this:

```
-(void)updateCompletedStatusAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath toStatus:(BOOL)status{
NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
NSMutableDictionary *currentsection = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[tableData objectAtIndex:section]];
NSMutableArray *itemsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[currentsection objectForKey:@"categoryItems"] copyItems:YES];
NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[itemsArray objectAtIndex:row]];
NSLog(@"BOOL = %@\n", (status ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
[tempDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:status] forKey:@"isComplete"];
[itemsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:row withObject:tempDict];
[currentsection setValue:itemsArray forKey:@"categoryItems"];
[tableData replaceObjectAtIndex:section withObject:currentsection];

[tempDict release];
[itemsArray release];
[currentsection release];

[checklistTable reloadData];
```

}

Before I implemented the filtering and used the logic above on self.defaultChecklistItemsArray directly, it worked and saved the data when the switch was flipped.

Now when I first enter the app, it loads the array of data from nsuserdefaults. I navigate to the view with the table and it displays the data correctly there with the UISwitches all in the correct position given the data (some on, some off). When I tap one of the switches, then click the segmentedcontrol that does the filtering, the data reverts back to the state it was loaded in, implying that the flipping of the switch did not actually effect the data at all (even though I don't think I did a deep copy anywhere here so I figured it should be doing the right thing). Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you explain in more details what it is NOT doing? Have you traced it? Have you tried putting some log messages?

Comment: I added more information to the initial question in the final paragraph to help clarify.

Comment: I guess the heart of the question is basically that if you have an array full of dictionaries and you filter the array based on criteria and use that to create a copy, how then do you deal with editing since you are viewing a copy?

Comment: as a matter of fact, i think an answer could be given to your answer, but it's probably complicated and I'm pretty sure you don't really have to 'copy' to accomplish the same task.

Comment: I'm certainly not attached to copying, I've just seen that method used in some examples that did filtering of tables. If you could point me in the direction of a better way, I'm all ears. :)